# Finding empty label in Windows form

Tags: winforms

I am new to Windows Form application and trying to build a small application.

I had dragged and dropped a label on the main form.

Then I deleted its text property to empty string basically hiding the label.

Now I would like to move this label to some other location on the form but unable to do so because I cannot find it.

I checked the designer file and its there.

But I cannot find it in the form so that I can grab it and move to a different location.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: use `<TAB>` to cycle through the controls till you have it - also drag-select should work with the mouse - finally you can set the text property int the "desinger-generated code" and it will reapear ...

Comment: Either select it from the combobox that is at the top of the Properties window or use the View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline window.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Document Outline. Look at the following images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That happens to me several times, and a few weeks ago I found a way to get the empty label like this:

On the tab "Properties" just click on the arrow to show all controls and click on the label you want, this will automatically select the label on your form..

[image]